# How to know who is knocking on the door (or port)?

Tags: ports

Having a Linux server with only one port open 22, how can I log attempts to connect to any other port? They are closed, but I'd still want to know.

Comment: This is more of a networking questions than a security question in my opinion.

Comment: a firewall can log this for you

Comment: IPTables can be configured to log traffic using the -j LOG option.  See [this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/iptables-log-packets/)

Comment: If you are only interested in logging at certain times, actively rather than passively, you can use wireshark. See [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `LOG` action in the iptables command, so your rule for checking connection attempts to all ports other than port 22 would be something like:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 ! --dport 22 -j LOG
```

This way, any connection which wasn't to port 22 will be logged into your system log.